# PHP Mailer error: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

Here is my code:

```
require 'phpmailertesting/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'send.one.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myemailhidden';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypasswordhidden';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also     accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'myemailhidden';
$mail->FromName = 'My Name';
$mail->addAddress('example@example.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

I have tried changing the port and the type of secure connection to "TSL" and "SSL" and nothing. Ive looked at the answers already and none of them solve it. Any answers? Thanks

I enabled the SMTP debugger and this is what it said "Connection: opening to ssl://send.one.com:465, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2014-12-15 15:46:40   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2014-12-15 15:46:40 SMTP connect() failed"

Comment: `telnet send.one.com 465` works for me. Take out the `$mail->SMTPSecure` line altogether and see if that works?

Comment: Tried it. Still failed with same error :(

Comment: Who is your web host? There may be some outgoing IPTables rules preventing you from communicating from port 465.

Comment: one.com. Im going to try using my google account. see if that works :)

Comment: Nope. doesn't work with gmail email :( what is going on here !

Comment: It's their way of saying that you need to find a better ISP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hosting company, one.com, blocks outgoing mail ports intentionally to restrict malicious PHP scripts. The `send.one.com` address is meant for external mail clients such as your mobile phone, email client, etc. and not for internal mailing scripts from your website.

As per their [support document](http://www.one.com/en/support/faq/can-i-send-mails-from-my-website) concerning sending emails from your website, you must change the host to their internal SMTP address, `mailout.one.com` - since this is an internal relay, you must also use port 25 and disable any security such as TLS or SSL. You must also disable authentication.

Here is the correct configuration:

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // Authentication must be disabled
$mail->Username = 'myemailhidden';
$mail->Password = ''; // Leave this blank
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

Comment: Still no luck :( same error message. really strange !

Comment: @SteMain Disable authentication, and remove the username/password fields. Make sure your "From" address belongs to your hosting domain.

Comment: yes it worked. I used port 25, no auth. What does this mean? something to do with one.com?

Comment: @SteMain That's right. one.com is doing it likely for security reasons - but this problem is particular to your hosting company and won't likely be found with many other hosts.

Comment: @SteMain Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me - would you be so kind to show the complete settings which worked for you? Thx!

Comment: @user4324207 you can try my solution, it's tested and should work.

Comment: @sjagr: I tried with your answer..for me, now it shows message cent.. still i didnt receive any mail..

Comment: @saina That's outside the scope of this question and answer. You should check for other SO questions that talk about messages that have been sent but not received by the recipient, and start a new SO question if you can't find anything that solves your problem. Best of luck.

Comment: @sjagr: yes after all.. finally, i post a question.. but still i didnt get .. anyway thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions did not work for me; this one did:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                            // disable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '[your one.com-email]';
$mail->Password = '[your one.com-email password]';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';                            // leave this blank!
$mail->Port = 25;
```

Let me know if it helped you, too!

Answer (score -1):

New to SO, so cant vote gold on you @sjagr

Had this problem, and as I use one.com, there were no biggey with the solution from @sjagr :)

You can try this full output in you file, and make sure to link the required docs.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "mailout.one.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->From = 'your@domain.se';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('sendtothis@domain.se');
$mail->addReplyTo('ireply@domain.se', 'Information');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'hejehej';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
if(!$mail->send()) {

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {

    echo 'Message has been sent, ja e fan inte tom';

} ?>
```